# Using Onboard Swift Library but it's showing up as blank?

Tags: ios, swift, bwwalkthrough

I have a normal view controller setup on my storyboard attached to a "Landing" page swift view controller class. I'm trying to create a walkthrough animation, using this popular library: https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard

I downloaded the 4 files from the library's source code, and linked them in my project using a bridging header. But when I run the project, I'm stuck. The page is blank, and nothing is showing up. The Onboard page titles, images, nothing. It's blank. I can't see what's wrong, and I've searched everywhere, no info or any Swift example of using this library.

Can someone help?

Here's the code I have in a function that's called during viewDidLoad() of the "Landing" class.

```
let firstPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Page Title 1", body: "Page body goes here.", image: UIImage(named: "icon"), buttonText: "Text For Button") { () -> Void in
        // do something here when users press the button, like ask for location services permissions, register for push notifications, connect to social media, or finish the onboarding process
    }

    firstPage.titleTextColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let secondPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Page Title 2", body: "Page body goes here.", image: UIImage(named: "icon"), buttonText: "Text For Button") { () -> Void in
        // do something here when users press the button, like ask for location services permissions, register for push notifications, connect to social media, or finish the onboarding process
    }

    // Image
    let onboardingVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "street_view.png"), contents: [firstPage, secondPage])


    self.presentViewController(onboardingVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try adding a break point and see if its hitting??

Comment: @vinbhai4u the app doesn't crash though, i use breakpoints to diagnose a crash. where should the breakpoint be added, and why?

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in a Objective-C Demo App [here](https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard/blob/master/Demo/Demo%20Files/AppDelegate.m), you should include this code inside your AppDelegate, under the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, and set the `rootViewController` properly. Here's an example (not tested):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  

    let firstPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Page Title 1", body: "Page body goes here.", image: UIImage(named: "icon"), buttonText: "Text For Button") { () -> Void in
            // do something here 
        }

    firstPage.titleTextColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    let secondPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Page Title 2", body: "Page body goes here.", image: UIImage(named: "icon"), buttonText: "Text For Button") { () -> Void in
           // do something here 
        }

    // Image
    let onboardingVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "street_view.png"), contents: [firstPage, secondPage])

    // Setting the BG color
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    // Setting the rootViewController to your onboardingVC
    self.window?.rootViewController = onboardingVC

    return true
    }
```

Comment: I ended up using another library (BWWalkthrough), but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

if you stick your code in the viewWillAppear() event it will all render.